# No Guest Checkout in PayPal Chained/Simple Payment [Android]

Tags: android, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I had referred the android sample application (Application Name: [PizzaApp-Complete](https://github.com/paypal/tech-talks/tree/master/AndroidDevCamp-March2011)) which is provided by PayPal. The Application is based on Simple Payment. While transferring money to **Business-Pro Account**, the PayPal is not asking for Guest Payment.It directly shows paypal login dialog. I am using Sand-Box for testing. **Why PayPal is not asking for Guest Payment? Also I had upgraded my Business Account to Business Account Pro, so that it will accept Credit/Debit payments made by user.**

Answer (score 1):

Check in your PayPal profile under Payment Receiving Preferences and make sure PayPal Account Optional is enabled.

Comment: PayPal Account Optional is already enable.  The issue may be because the sample application is using PayPal MPL library,which may not support direct payment.

Comment: It does.  It could be a cookie issue.  Try clearing the cache and cookies in your browser.  Sometimes it'll hide the guest checkout option when it assumes you'll be logging in to an account.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the legacy MPL does not support guest checkout.